# List of Strings to Links

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, hyperlink, textbox

i was wondering if it is possible in c# to set to a text box a list of strings that are clickable links? at the moment i can set the text box like this

```
txtBox.Lines = values.ToArray();
```

ideally though i would like them as links if possible? maybe link labels or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use RichTextBox and check this - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/RichTextBoxLinks.aspx

Answer (score 2):

(I'm assuming you're using Windows Forms; the answer for WPF/Silverlight may be slightly different.)

A textbox just contains text - it's not "rich" enough to have links.

If you want a *list* you might want to consider using a `ListBox` of some description - or possibly a `RichTextBox`; I haven't tried creating links in a `RichTextBox`, so I don't know whether it's possible.

Of course, you haven't specified what you want to happen when the user clicks on the links, either...

Comment: for now nothing needs to happen - just want to get the core functionality for now and add the specifics later

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [`Windows.Forms.Controls.LinkLabel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.linklabel.aspx). It allows storing multiple links along with the text in it.